# Is there a way to disable recursive make?

Tags: gnu-make

If I have a makefile I have to use that is using recursive make, is there an easy option to disable that?

http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf

Comment: I think this question should better asked at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  If you invoke `make` even once in `Makefile`, it would be called a recursive make.  There's no easy option in GNU Make to prevent it.

Once you read the paper mentioned in your post, you could understand it's determined by how you write `Makefile`s whether the make is recursive or non-recursive.

[Linux kernel build system](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt) would be one of the most famous applications of traditional recursive make in large scale.  [Android build system](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build.git/+/master/core/build-system.html) is a good example of non-recursive make, which is explicitly addressing problems of recursive make.  Both build systems are exploiting GNU Make specific features intensively.